# What is the interior and limit points of the set $\{(1/(2^n))+(1/(5^m)) \}$when $n$ and $m$ are in $\mathbb{N}$ and also this set is open or closed?

Tags: analysis

To solve this problem, I consider this point that $n$ and $m$ are intended to the big numbers, so the limit point is $0$ and also this set is open because the limit point is not inset. Am I right?
About the interior point, I don't know the right answer.

Comment: Hint: No countable set can have an interior point.

Comment: Hello, you should consider also adding the problem down in the body parts of the question.